# Erro 500 ao usar .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Rescrevi um regra no `.htaccess` para retirar a extensão `.php` da minha página `dashboard.php` mas o *WAMP* me retorna:

> erro 500

Comment: faltou dizer qual o código que adicionas-te para este erro aparecer.

Comment: Seria bom postar o .htaccess na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é um problema de mod_rewrite desabilitado, siga os passos abaixo.

Abra o arquivo httpd.conf, procure pela linha:

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

e descomente removendo o símbolo “#” do início da linha para ficar assim:

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Procure também pela linha

`AllowOverride None`

e altere para

`AllowOverride All`

> Após isso reinicie o wampserver!

Comment: Obrigado, realmente era esse o problema.

Comment: Por nada, se resolveu você pode estar marcando minha resposta como a correta :) obrigado!